# Displaying Label Inside Text-area

Tags: html, css, forms, layout, textarea

I want to make a square shape text area of fixed size.The label of the text-area will be inside the text-area as shown in the picture below.This heading will always be displayed.It will not dissapear on entering text inside the text area like a placeholder.

I tried it in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jwB2Y/2/ but was not able to place it inside the text-area..

The CSS code..

```
      label 
      { 
         float: top; 
         width:120px;
         padding:10px 10px;
         font-weight:bold;
      }
```

The Desired Output..

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Since i couldn't palce the label inside the text area i placed it above it using the float:top property..

Comment: This question is different from the question "Position Label on top of text-area".I need to dispaly labels in different ways thats why i created a seperate question...

Comment: what do you mean by "displaying labels in different ways"?

Answer (score 2):

I moved the label under the textarea and added the following CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/kkctL/1/

```
textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
label { 
    display: block;
    margin: -330px 5px 0 5px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: As @Lucy wanted to have a square, the textarea height should be 270px and the label margin-top 300px

Comment: @HighKickX Shouldn't the label be inside the textarea?

Comment: I want the secondary heading to also not dissapear like the main heading as seen in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kkctL/3/

Answer (score 1):

try this;

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative; 
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    width:350px;
    padding:10px;
}
.wrapper .first-heading { 
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.wrapper .second-heading {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
.wrapper .textarea1{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    border:none; 
    outline:none;   
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <label for="qual" >The main heading underlined:</label> 
    <textarea id="qual" rows="5" cols="20" style="resize:none" placeholder="The secondary heading of this space in brackets"></textarea>
</div>
```

New Jsfiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/jwB2Y/7/
Old Jsfiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/jwB2Y/5/

Comment: I want the secondary heading to also not dissapear like the main heading as seen in this fiddle jsfiddle.net/kkctL/3

Comment: @Lucy I changed the above code the way you want and I've added a new jsfiddle.Can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely position the label over the text area and then add some top padding to the textarea. Remove 'float:top' as this doesn't do anything.

Comment: yes i made the changes here http://jsfiddle.net/jwB2Y/3/ but it still hasn't solved my problem..

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the whole lot in a `div`, then place a `span` inside the `label` to format the font:

**CSS**

```
div {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  padding:10px;
}
span { 
  display:block; 
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
label {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
textarea {
  border:none;
  width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label for="qual"><span>The main heading underlined </span>Sub heading</label>      
  <textarea id="qual" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="Placeholder text"></textarea>
</div>
```

see updated demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwB2Y/6/).